# How to chage style & color produced numbering of PageableListView

Tags: wicket

i used PageableListView in my table but the numbering produced in following simple
    format:

```
<< < 1 2 3 4 > >> 

with blue color .please tell how to change color & style of such PageableListView in   
wicket
```

Comment: Are you using `DefaultDataTable` ?

Comment: @jordeu:no dude i was not used DefaultDataTable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write CSS to change the color of `a` elements :

```
a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active{
  color:black;
}
```